How to apply multiple coupon in Magento 2.4.7?
In Magento 2.4.7, now multiple coupon is supported.
Shoppers can apply multiple coupons to a cart. Merchants can also apply multiple coupons using shopping assistance.
However after applied one coupon on cart page, the input box dimmed and not able to add others.
Is it a bug or extra configuration is needed?


Magento already replied me on the multi-coupon feature.
The product team confirmed that the multicoupon feature is currently available only for use with REST or GraphQL. It is not available for consumption from the storefront with the default Luma theme. The same thing is mentioned in the 2.4.7 release note.
They also requested the doc team to update the configuration document, and also add a note in the backend multicoupon configuration indicating this limitation
Updated: 9May2024
Magento team finally updated the document to explain that it is not available in Storefront.
Official documentation
Determines the maximum number of coupons allowed per order. This feature is available in Admin, GraphQL and REST API only. And it is not available in Storefront.

Unfortunately, this feature is only available in Adobe Commerce, not in Magento Open Source. This information is misleading and it comes from the Document team at Adobe.
To verify this, navigate to the store configuration in the Admin by going to Store > Settings > Configuration > Sales > Sales.
In Adobe Commerce, you will find the Maximum number of coupons per order config field under the Multicoupon Settings group.
You can check out the documentation at https://experienceleague.adobe.com/en/docs/commerce-admin/config/sales/sales#:~:text=the%20manufacturer%20(MSRP).-,Multicoupon%20Settings,-Exclusive%20feature%20only

I  tried, but the frontend input is still not allowed to input further coupon.
However if I create admin order in backend, multiple coupon works for backend order.
Did you use a brand new commerce 2.4.7 and see if it works?

I currently don't have a brand new commerce 2.4.7, but I am willing to help you investigate the issue.
